# Characterization of convex dual-like functions

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, locally-convex-spaces

Let $f$ be a proper, convex, lsc functional from, a locally-convex topological vector space, $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Then by Fenchel-Monreau Theorem,
$$
f(x)
=\sup \left \{ \left. \left\langle x^{\star} , x \right\rangle - f^{\star} \left( x^{\star} \right) \right| x^{\star} \in X^{\star} \right\}
$$ where the convex-conjugate $f^{\star}$ is defined by
$$
f^{\star}\left( x^{\star} \right) := \sup \left \{ \left. \left\langle x^{\star} , x \right\rangle - f \left( x \right) \right| x \in X \right\}
.
$$

Is there a characterization of the proper, lsc, convex functionals $g:X^{\star}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f(x)=\sup \left \{ \left. \left\langle x^{\star} , x \right\rangle - g\left( x^{\star} \right) \right| x^{\star} \in X^{\star} \right\}
?
$$

Comment: Any reason why you don't expect $g=f^*$? The double conjugate of a closed convex function is the function itself, after all.

Comment: In the reflexive case it's obvious that's $g=f^{\star}$, but I saw (potentially eronious) example recently in the non reflexive case..